# ElementClickInterceptedException in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have this page: https://tinyzonetv.to/tv/watch-marvels-daredevil-2015-free-39196

And I want to click on every 'season' with selenium.

But it returns me this exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <li id="season-2891"> is not clickable at point (369,21) because another element <div id="onesignal-slidedown-container" class="onesignal-slidedown-container onesignal-reset slide-down"> obscures it
```

But I already used waits and ActionChains, but it still doesn't work. Can you suggest me something?

Comment: It might have something to do with frames. Try reading more [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. there is not code to reproduce the case. Dont add screenshot of code.

Comment: first show code which you use for this - maybe you try to click unclickable element, or there is other element which hides this clickable element and it can't click it.